# Http StatusCode 404, but still content exists

Tags: http, http-headers

I tried to ping some pages, to see if they are still available and thought it a good idea to rely on the http-status code.
Now I have discovered that there are some pages, which send me a 404 code but still have content that the browser shows. I always thought a 404 code would be handeled by the browser as not reachable. How is this possible?
Here is an example page:
http://example.org/referring_page
Chrome shows me content but in the developer tool (F12) it shows me a 404 code.

So in the end, does that mean that I cant rely on that code and it would be better to check the content somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 means that the page you asked for doesn't exist. The *content* of the 404 message could be anything, an error message, a feedback form, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that a default page is sent, which content I could parse. I had other examples where it was not a default error page, but was because of bad java coding :)